# Virtual host setup in local host magento 2

Tags: magento2, hosting

I installed magento **2.2.4** and (name directory SA ) i want to have  in the url **sa.com.tn** and for admin **sa.com.tn/interBO/admin** so i tried to open `sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf` but it is  empty so how to do that and why this file is empty. please i need your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create configuration file for host

> sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
>   /etc/apache2/sites-available/sa.com.conf

Now, modify the configuration files to match with our virtual hosts and put below code.

> sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/sa.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin magento2@test.com
    ServerName sa.com.tn
    ServerAlias www.sa.com.tn
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/SA
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/SA>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable virtual host configuration files

> sudo a2ensite sa.com.conf

Restart apache web server.

> sudo service apache2 restart

Add your virtual host like below and put code.

> gedit /etc/hosts
>
> 127.0.0.1 sa.com.tn

Now edit core_config_data table and put url here like below

> http://sa.com.tn/

Comment: thanks  for your replay , what about the admin url how to change it

Comment: For apache version 2.4 :
Require all granted instead of Order allow,deny allow from all

Comment: @Ansar can you help check out this question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294677/apache-virtual-host-setup-configuration-in-localhost-for-multiple-magento-sites thank you.

Comment: Great, thanks @ansar

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.x is not supported Windows OS and Mac OS due security reasons however we can still install Magento 2 on Windows machine using XAMPP tool, but we must fix some known errors after installing on Windows system. 
Check this link for more details. 
https://www.howtoinmagento.com/2019/06/magento-2x-does-not-support-windows-mac.html