# Apache Virtual host setup configuration in localhost for multiple magento sites

Tags: server-setup, localhost, apache, apache2, ubuntu

I have two Magento 2 instances in my Virtualbox ubuntu server.
1st one is new installation magento2.3 located at 
`/var/www/html/`, it is working fine and accessible from the browser using IP `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

The 2nd instance is a cloned version of production site Magento 2.2.9, located at `/var/www/html2/`. I'm able to run `bin/magento commands` from the command line, however, I'm not able to access the site from the browser.

How do I modify the configuration file for hosts at  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` to work with multiple Magento sites?

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/newsite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@admin.com
            ServerName localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/newsite2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@admin.com
        ServerName localhost2
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html2

        <Directory /var/www/html2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost2
```

Comment: why you are making two html directory , i think you should use one html directory and just add another project name inside html directory for another site and assign virtual host for it . As appache map with html directory that's why its not running html2 in browser

Comment: Set up Magento 2.2.9 in `/var/www/html/m229` and check it.

Comment: i looked up some tutorials with the above setup, thought that it'll work and looks cleaner. moved it to under /html/ with some permission updates fixed the issue. thanks