# Magento isin't installing and getting "Not found" error

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm trying to install and run Magento 2.4.3 (latest current version) on my mac and I'm getting the following error when I try opening up the browser to localhost:

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

I started by installing MAMP and set Port apache: 80; MySQL: 3306. Next, I installed composer. I then downloaded [magento from github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases/tag/2.4.3) and moved the extracted folder here: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`.

Now when I go to `http://localhost/magento2-2.4.3/` it says `The requested URL was not found on this server.` What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Need to setup virtual hosts : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245721/virtual-host-setup-in-local-host-magento-2